# What are pros/cons of using MSSQL SDE Database rather than File Geodatabase in ArcGIS Server

Tags: arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase, file-geodatabase, sql-server

I have taken over an ArcSDE 9.3 Enterprise database setup which has around 80% of it´s vector data in an MSSQL SDE Database system and 20% in File GDB on the application server. I am trying to understand if there is a logical reason as to why someone would set this up.

Can anyone offer reasons why a MSSQL SDE Database is prefered to File Geodatabases?

Versioning is not being used in either case. The web clients which have read/write access seem to all be in the MSSQL SDE DB. There are also 6 SDE Services running although most of the connects are direct.